# return only whole match word using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string `"myname 18-may 1234"` and I want only `"1234"` from whole string using a regex.

I tried using the `\b([0-9]*)\b` regex and that gave me `"18"` and `"1234"` as a result.

But i want only `"1234"` not `"18"`  Please suggest the correct way to select only `"1234"` from whole word.

also string are change in sometime string appears like `"18-may 1234 myname"` or `"18-may myname 1234"`

Is it possible - to get `1234` only, not `18`?

Comment: Is the "1234" portion always going to be longer than the "18" portion? (I realise that these are just examples)

Comment: `\d+(?![-\w])` try this.

Comment: With the answer I provided, does your issue still remain?

Comment: Please show us how you test the regexps.

Comment: please explain me why my question are down voted if you do not expalin then please upvote my question@stribizhev

Comment: There are plenty of reasons that I've seen that cause a question to get down voted.  Most common reasons that I've seen is that the question don't follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or the there is no effort shown in the OP to solve the issue.

Comment: I have not downvoted but the question lacks clarity since appropriate solutions have been suggested and were said to be incorrect. What are the exact requirements and what are potential contexts like? Again, this was my answer: [`(?<=^|\s)\d+(?=\s|$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5cs)%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%5cs%7c%24)&i=myname+804+805-way) - what is wrong with it?

Comment: So, did you get any of the answers work for you? I will only consider upvoting the question after I understand what you need.

Comment: no i not getting any answer that work for me but i fnd that answer               (?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)  so now up vote my question@stribizhev

Comment: I don't get it: your regex that matches numbers surrounded with non-digits will match both `18` and `1234` in `myname 18-may 1234`. Once I understand the requirements I will be able to answer and upvote your question. Also how about accepting my answer to your previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you replace the `*` quantifier in `[0-9]*` with `[0-9]{n,}` where `n` is the number of digits you at least expect, the regexp should only return 1234 in your example if you use `[0-9]{3,}`

Answer (score 0):

The sample data you're providing looks like a name and birthday where the year (3 or more digits) can be found anywhere in the `string`.  If that's true, then this pattern will extract a number with 3 or more digits out of the string:

```
\\d{3,}
```

Tested @ [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oM2vT3/1)

Comment: @kap Can you explain how?

Comment: if enter 123 then this solution are not proper

Comment: @kap Perhaps you should have clarified that in your question.

Comment: sorry bro 3 digit minmum

Comment: ill upvote your answer because these downvotes feel rly unfair :)

Comment: @h3n Appreciate that.  It's always nice to know why I get down voted, so even I can improve.

Comment: please explain me why my question are down voted if you do not expalin then please upvote my question@Shar1er80

Comment: please explain me why my question are down voted if you do not expalin then please upvote my question@h3n